# Trouble updating GT-p1000 p1000jxjj1

Tags: updates, samsung-galaxy-tab

I have a *GT-p1000* running Android 2.2 (p1000jxjj1) with Kernel 2.6.32.9, and want to update the device.

I began the steps as described on the Web site, used Odin to put the Ram file and then clicked "start" till the pass. But I ended up with the Samsung logo on the screen, which never changed.

Is there any solution?

Comment: Maybe you add some more information -- e.g. what web site (link) and which update file(s) you were using?